# on MAC OS X, py.test not recognized as a command

Tags: python, macos, pytest

On MAC OS X 10.10; I installed pytest 2.6.4; however in Terminal If I write py.test or even py.test --version; I get the error:

```
-bash: py.test command not found
```

(a) Am I missing anything? What do I do to make the pytest tool recognizable.
I searched alot; but couldn't find any info except http://teckla.idyll.org/~t/transfer/py.test.html

I checked in the PyCharm preferences, I don't see py.test interpreter listed there. However, pip freeze displays pytest 2.6.4 installed.

(b) Is PYTHONPATH required to be set on MAC? Although I've seen setting it is not required on Windows.

Appreciate any pointers to help me resolve this.

---

Update: Contents of my bash_profile:

```
echo export PATH="HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
PATH="/Users/admin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages:$PATH"
PATH="/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

Comment: How did you install it? Did you rehash your shell completion after installing it.  Do you know where it was installed and if so is that directory in your PATH?

Comment: I did pip install -U pytest

Comment: In WIndows, we append PATH variable with "C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts" to make the python tests run; so what's is the equivalent for MAC?

Comment: assuming you haven't changed your shell you would need to add something like export PATH=$PATH:/path/dir/with/py.test in ~/.profile to add it to your path (IN *nix ; pathsep is :)      How did you install pip? (homebrew?)  is located in  /usr/local/bin ?  you can try to find where  py.test is located. (try typing this in a terminal ` find  / -name py.test -print` which should show you where it is,   but also check as @I'L'I said to make sure that it has its executable bit set

Comment: @Doon on OS X `~/.bash_profile` should be used and not `~/.profile`.

Comment: Yeah well .profile is read last so it will still work if .bash_profile doesn't exist but it should also work across all sh versions. . I don't use bash so sorry about the wrong location.

Comment: I did restart my Terminal after the changes. Here's the content of bash_profile; what's wrong with this? It still does not recognize py.test command.     

echo export PATH="HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
PATH="/Users/admin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages:$PATH"
PATH="/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

Comment: @Doon, @l'L'l; please guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it worked finally! 
After downloading pytest, I ran the following commands and it worked like magic. I think,earlier, I missed putting "sudo" infront of the install command:

```
$python setup.py build
$sudo python setup.py install
```

The output said:

```
..
Installing py.test script to /usr/local/bin
Installing py.test-2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Installed /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pytest-2.6.4-py2.7.egg
..
Using /Users/admin/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
Finished processing dependencies for pytest==2.6.4
```

My .bash_profile contents, jfyr:

```
PATH="/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin"
export PATH
```

Comment: my guess is that when you ran it as your user it installed it into a directory in your homedir,  and that directory was not in your path..

Comment: You are right. I think when I first did install pytest with --user attribute. `code`"python setup.py install --user"`code`

Answer (score 5):

On OS X you should do:

```
pip install -U pytest
```

or

```
easy_install -U pytest
```

http://pytest.org/latest/getting-started.html

Comment: I actually did this. But then If I do py.test --version; I get the error "-bash: py.test command not found"

Comment: Did you quit terminal and re-launch? You might also need to `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/py.test`

Comment: Yes, I did quit the terminal and re-launched and even did chmod  +x <py.test directory>; but it did not help. Please see my original post where I just added the contents of my bash_profile

Answer (score 2):

For those of us trying to avoid any and all use of `sudo`:

1. [Download from PyPI here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytest#downloads) and unpack.
2. `$ cd <pytest download folder>`
3. `$python setup.py build`
4. `$python setup.py install --user`
5. Wherever the installing output says the "py.test script" has been installed to, add to `PATH` in your .bash_profile (or .bashrc if you use that for environment variables).
6. Confirm the setup worked via `$py.test --version`

Answer (score 2):

pip3 install -U pytest is working with version Python 3.7

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem installing pytest on Mac M1 but I followed the python pip documentation and it worked. What i did was:

- istalled pip via command in Pycharm terminal (I use pycharm): python3 -m pip install pytest
- after installation I run the pytest from the terminal with a command : python3 -m pytest "name_of_the_file.py"

And that works. On Mac I need to prefix all commands with "python3" cause I guess Mac has its own inbuild Python but thats Python 2 so in order to run code on my Pycharm, which was Python 3 , I need that prefix in the command... not sure though I am a newbie but something along those lines I guess