# py.test: command not found

Tags: python, pip, macports

I installed pytest via MacPorts:

```
sudo port install py34-pytest
```

but it doesn't work:

```
py.test --version
-bash: pytest: command not found
```

pip freeze shows it as installed. If I install it via pip instead of ports the same thing happens.

Comment: This doesn't help your problem, but is an advice. I would recommend creating virtualenv and then installing py.test with pip, as this is more platform neutral and more community supported way to install packages: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html

Comment: Should I do this for every package? And install all python related packages with pip instead of macports? I already installed pylint.

Comment: possible duplicate of [on MAC OS X, py.test not recognized as a command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098876/on-mac-os-x-py-test-not-recognized-as-a-command)

Comment: the file setup.py doesn't exist on my machine

Comment: @kiwi: Yes, install everything to a virtualenv (no sudo!) using pip and you get the best error reports if things do not work

Comment: Why no sudo? Virtualenv has the same 'command not found' problem. Do I have to change the PATH?

Comment: Oh, the virtualenv.py is there and can be executed from the directory, but as a bash command it doesn't work